# Browser Console full of errors in IceFaces 3.3.0

Tags: icefaces-3

As the title says, my browser console is really full of errors some of which are as follows:

Error: ReferenceError: **css_ims** is not defined

Error: TypeError: **br.log** is undefined

Error: TypeError: **window.ice.onLoad** is not a function

Error: TypeError: **ice.captureSubmit** is not a function

Error: TypeError: **ice.setupBridge** is not a function

Error: TypeError: **ice.push** is undefined

Error: TypeError: **ice.captureSubmit** is not a function

Error: TypeError: **ice.onBeforeSubmit** is not a function

And guys let me also tell you about the Icefaces version I used:
1. **icefaces-3.3.0.jar**
2. **icefaces-ace-3.3.0.jar**
3. **icefaces-compat-3.3.0.jar**
4. **icefaces-mobi-1.2.0.jar**
5. **icepush-3.3.0.jar**

Prior to the use of these **3.3.0** versions and **icefaces-mobi-1.2.0.jar** I was using 3.0.1 versions and no use of **icefaces-mobi-1.2.0.jar** in which the browser console was having none of the above mentioned errors. So I was thinking this might be the compatibility issue.

(**Note:Here the icefaces mobi jar is used for Mobile related things.**)

Thanks in advance. Any help would greatly be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if adding ICEmobile is causing these JavaScript errors, but ICEmobile 1.2.0 is designed to be used with ICEfaces 3.2.0. For ICEfaces 3.3.0 you should use ICEmobile 1.3.0. Also be sure to clear your browser cache before retrying.

Answer (score 0):

Those errors occurs because all/some icefaces javascript files are not downloaded to the client.
I faced this problem: I investigated this issue using firebug(firefox plug-in) and I found that all resources URL which includes (javax.faces.resource) are giving 302 response error which means that the request is redirected.
I double check and found that I have (**javax.servlet.Filter**) called **AuthenticationFilter** which filters all the requests, and if the user doesn't login all requests are redirected to the login page.
To solve this issue: in ***AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,FilterChain chain)***

I added the if statement:

```
if (path.contains("javax.faces.resource") || path.contains("/css") || path.contains("/images") || path.contains("/js")) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response); // Just continue chain.
    return;
}
```